# How to construct Data/NSData from UnsafeMutablePointer<T>

Tags: ios, swift, openssl

**Background**: I am using OpenSSL library to create PKCS12 file in Swift. I have the certificate and private key stored in Keychain.

**Problem**: I am able to create a PKCS12 file and store it in the app bundle successfully. When I want to use the PKCS12 file (e.g. Receive a auth challenge from a HTTPS server), I can load the file by using `SecPKCS12Import()` function provided by Apple. Now, instead of generating a physical file, I want to generate the PKCS12 object in flight whenever I need it. It will be stored in memory. Since I am new to Swift, I am seeking help for converting from UnsafeMutablePointer to Data.
You will understand more when you read my following code:

Previously, I have my `createP12` function implemented as:

```
createP12(pemCert: String, pemPK: String) {
    // .......
    // Code to load certificate and private key Object..

    guard let p12 = PKCS12_create(passPhrase, name, privateKey, certificate, nil, NID_pbe_WithSHA1And3_Key_TripleDES_CBC, NID_pbe_WithSHA1And3_Key_TripleDES_CBC, 0, 0, 0) else {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr)
        return
    }

    // Save p12 to file
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let tempDirectory = NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString
    let path = tempDirectory.appendingPathComponent("ssl.p12")

    fileManager.createFile(atPath: path, contents: nil, attributes: nil)
    guard let fileHandle = FileHandle(forWritingAtPath: path) else {
        LogUtils.logError("Cannot open file handle: \(path)")
        return
    }
    let p12File = fdopen(fileHandle.fileDescriptor, "w")

    i2d_PKCS12_fp(p12File, p12)
    fclose(p12File)
    fileHandle.closeFile()
}
```

Then when I want to read the p12 file, I can call

```
let p12Data = NSData(contentsOfFile: Bundle.main.path(forResource: mainBundleResource, ofType:resourceType)!)! as Data
var items: CFArray?
let certOptions: NSDictionary = [kSecImportExportPassphrase as NSString: passwordStr as NSString]
self.securityError = SecPKCS12Import(p12Data as NSData, certOptions, &items)
// Code to read attributes
```

From `createP12()` function, I firstly got a p12 object in type of `UnsafeMutablePointer<PKCS12>` then store it in the file. Instead, now I want to pass p12 directly to the pkcs12 reader function. To do so, I have to firstly convert p12 object into a Data/NSData object since that's what required by `SecPKCS12Import()` function.

So, long story short, how can I construct a Data/NSData object from the p12 object which is in type of `UnsafaMutablePointer<PKCS12>` thus I can pass it into `SecPKCS12Import()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work (it compiles but I could not test it). The idea is to write the PKCS12 object to a memory buffer and then create `Data`
from the buffer:

```
func p12ToData(p12: UnsafeMutablePointer<PKCS12>) -> Data {

    // Write PKCS12 to memory buffer:
    let mbio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem())
    i2d_PKCS12_bio(mbio, p12)

    // Get pointer to memory buffer and number of bytes. The
    //   # define BIO_get_mem_data(b,pp)  BIO_ctrl(b,BIO_CTRL_INFO,0,(char *)pp)
    // macro is not imported to Swift.
    var ptr = UnsafeRawPointer(bitPattern: 1)!
    let cnt = BIO_ctrl(mbio, BIO_CTRL_INFO, 1, &ptr)

    // Create data from pointer and count:
    let data = Data(bytes: ptr, count: cnt)

    // Release memory buffer:
    BIO_free(mbio)

    return data
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works perfect! I thought about creating a buffer by using BIO_new, but wasn't able to figure out how to get the cnt and how to construct the data. Anyways, thanks so much for your kind help!